# Control Input Devices with .NET, is it possible?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, input-devices

I have a gaze controller with their respective .NET SDK.

I'm wondering if there is any way to create an application/process in .NET where through code I can control cursor movement (and actions: click, double click…) in Windows SO and also to inject text (in anywhere such as, rename a icon, make a search in a browser), basically I want to control input devices (mouse, keyboard) through code in .NET.

Is it possible? What would I need for this? Where to start?

Excuse me if it is an inappropiate question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control cursor movement and clicks in windows from a .net application using the [Cursor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can send keyboard strokes to the active application in windows using the [SendKeys Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Both are quite straight forward, for example, to send an ENTER keypress all that is required is

```
 SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```